# JavaScript not loading in Drupal (8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, libraries

Im creating my first site in Drupal (converting an existing site over to the Drupal 8 CMS).

Ive loaded the CSS and Script libraries. The CSS is working but the Script files are not. Im not sure if its the script files not loading or jQuery not loading - or both.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code calling the libraries in the .info file:

```html
libraries:
  - saq7704/global-styles
  - saq7704/global-scripts
```

and here is the code in the libraries file:

```html
global-styles:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: {}

global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
  js: 
    js/scripts.js: {}
    js/responsiveTabs.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Comment: Did you place the js files in the exact same directory you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering that the CSS is loading. As you have to attach your libraries to some render array explicitly (element, node, page etc.). Declaring them in your module's info file shouldn't do anything at all.

Have a look at the docs on [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module).

To have your libraries loaded on every page you have to use [`hook_page_attachments`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.2.x):

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {

  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'saq7704/global-styles';
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'saq7704/global-scripts';

  // Also have a look at this gem.
  // If you've written your JS file the right way you now could do
  // <code>console.log(settings.MYMODULE.foo);</code> in your JS
  // and guess what it will print ;)
  $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['MYMODULE']['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

Read on how to write Drupal JS files the right way:
[JavaScript API overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) (watch out for `Drupal.behaviors`, `context` and `settings`). Then your `*.libraries.yml` should better look like:

```
global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
  js: 
    js/scripts.js: {}
    js/responsiveTabs.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Comment: Im a little confused... Do I need to change how the JS code is written in order for it to work in Drupal? Im quite new to writing JS as well so im not quite sure what im supposed to be changing.

Comment: @DaveP19 – You need to call that `MYMODULE_page_attachements` hook in your `MYMODULE.module` file. In your case that would be `saq7704_page_attachements` and `saq7704.module`.